# A word for the condition of being blasé

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, vocabulary, british-english

Is there a word in English that encapsulates the condition of being blasé, sort of in the same vein as "weariness" encapsulates the condition of being weary?

> blasé: having or showing a lack of excitement or interest in something especially because it has become familiar [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blas%C3%A9)

I would like a word that captures that idea of disinterest due to routine or familiarity.

Comment: *indifferent*? *jaded*? *French*?

Comment: @DanBron "French" sounds pretty good. However, can you think of anything sorta more specific?

Comment: Other than *indifferent* and *jaded*? Maybe *cynical*? Though that feels way too strong.

Comment: _Nonchalant_. (of a person or manner) feeling or appearing casually calm and relaxed; not displaying anxiety, interest, or enthusiasm.

Comment: _mundane_ might fit the bill

Comment: I think *jaded* is the only one that captures both the *disinterest* aspect and the *experienced-too-many-times-before* aspect of blasé.

Comment: All these examples are adjectives, and it sounds like the OP wants a noun.

Comment: I think he could arrive at *'nonchalance'* without too much of a stretch.

Comment: Sounds a bit like *ennui*. Or maybe *tedium*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that ***jadedness*** is considered to be a word: it appears in [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jaded) and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jadedness) and has over 4,000 hits on [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=jadedness&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):

> feeling or showing a lack of interest and excitement caused by having done or experienced too much of something [MW for *jaded*]

Another option, *apathy*, is much more popular, but the routine/familiarity aspect of the disinterest is not as clearly implied:

> the feeling of not having much emotion or interest [[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathy)]

Google Ngrams shows that [the use of *jadedness* is on the rise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jadedness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cjadedness%3B%2Cc0), but compared to *apathy*, it barely even registers:

[image: Jadedness vs. Apathy usage]

Answer (score 1):

***burned out*** or perhaps *burnt out*.

From Wikipedia's ["occupational burnout" article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occupational_burnout):

> **Burnout** is a type of psychological stress. Occupational burnout or job burnout is characterized by exhaustion, lack of enthusiasm and motivation, feelings of ineffectiveness, and also may have the dimension of frustration or cynicism, and as a result reduced efficacy within the workplace

And [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burnout):

> : the condition of someone who has become very physically and emotionally tired after doing a difficult job for a long time
>
> : a person who suffers burnout

I don't agree with Merriam's take that the job must be "difficult."  It may simply have become tedious.