# Difference between "jaded" and "blasé"

Tags: differences, adjectives, synonyms

I recently learned the word *blasé*, and couldn't seem to be able to figure out how it was different to *jaded*. The definitions are similar to each other, but they don't seem to be often used interchangeably.

> [Blasé](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/blase): *Unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before.*
>
> [Jaded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/jaded): *Bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something.*

(Both definitions are from Oxford Living Dictionaries.) I wanted to hear everyone's juxtaposition of the two.

Comment: Check out this similar post for some ideas about jaded and blasé:

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278145/a-word-for-the-condition-of-being-blas%C3%A9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words definitely have different meanings. blasé is defined by the [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blase) as

> Unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before:

while Jaded is described by the [same dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/jaded) as

> Bored or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something

The difference in usage is that *jaded* always has negative connotations. For example

"The HR manager was jaded by years of commuting. The crowded stations and over-full trains depressed her"

while *blasé* has connotations which are usually, at worst, neutral. For example

"After years of chart success the rock star was completely blasé about airport VIP lounges and flying first class"

It is, of course possible that the rock star could become jaded with constant touring but it would be the touring and the constant exposure to the media which would have jaded her, not the level of luxury associated with first class travel. Having become blasé about that she could well have begun to see it as normal.

You can also become blasé about negative things so that they no longer interfere with your enjoyment of an activity or ability to do your job. For example

"As an experienced winch man James was completely blasé about flying in a rescue helicopter with the side door open."

The only negative association of blasé arises when people become so used to dangerous situations that they no longer take proper care to mitigate the danger.

"Harry had worked so long as an aerial fitter that he had become blasé about working at heights and no longer checked that his ladder was steady before he climbed it. The fall killed him."