# Is there a word for when bizarre, incredible things become so common that you aren't fazed by them anymore?

Tags: single-word-requests, writing-advice

I'm trying to think of a phenomenon for my story where if you live in a sci-fi universe, the denizens don't really see new, amazing things like teleportation out of the ordinary because they already have FTL and robots. I need a word that describes amazing things being the norm so you aren't even fazed, if there even is such a word.

Comment: You mean like how wearing a computer on your wrist that can access a work-wide network of information is a common, everyday occurrence?  It’s just called normal.

Comment: For single word requests, please include a sample sentence with a blank where you'd like the word to fit.

Comment: Edit in at least one example usage, and leave blank where the word should fit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "jaded" and "blasé"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/358546/difference-between-jaded-and-blas%c3%a9)

Comment: Since you tagged this "writing-advice": don't. You're looking for a word to *tell* your readers how future people will naturally adjust to their world, when you should just *show* it.

Answer (score 8):

How about blasé?

'Unimpressed with or indifferent to something because one has experienced or seen it so often before.
"she was becoming quite blasé about the dangers"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

If the thing they got used to is something bad (especially morally or ethically, like violence or death, or something else they would previously have reacted negatively to), you could say they are *desensitized* to it:

> having been made less likely to feel shock or distress at scenes of cruelty or suffering by overexposure to such images. *people who view such movies become desensitized to violence*

— Oxford Dictionary of English

Comment: Does the thing have to be bad? Can it not be *desensitized to wonders*?

Answer (score 6):

If you "don't really see new, amazing things like teleportation out of the ordinary," these bizarre things become **commonplace**.

**commonplace** (adj.)

> Commonly found or seen : ORDINARY, UNREMARKABLE [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commonplace)

> If something is commonplace, it happens often or is often found, and
> is therefore **not surprising**. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/commonplace)

---

> In the classic Star Trek television series **teleportation was
> commonplace** from the deck of the USS *Enterprise*.  [Daniel H. Wilson;
> *Where's My Jetpack*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Where_s_My_Jetpack/-khRDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22teleportation%20was%20commonplace%22&pg=PT50&printsec=frontcover)

> With each new revelation, a media frenzy ensued, and consequently,
> even accounts of **people meeting aliens became commonplace** ...
> [Gary Bates; *Alien Intrusion*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Alien_Intrusion/SVh0noGKbhYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=With%20each%20new%20revelation,%20a%20media%20frenzy%20ensued,&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover)

> All I'm trying to say, captain, is that **levitation was commonplace** in
> Europe in the Middle Ages. In fact, it was so common that the Vatican
> ultimately decided not to count levitation as proof of a miracle when
> evaluating a holy person's candidacy for beatification and
> canonization." [Thomas Quealy; *Ordinary Magic*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ordinary_Magic/sHaKR1vXdB8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=levitation%20was%20commonplace&pg=PA116&printsec=frontcover)

---

When happenings that were once strange become commonplace, people are **unconcerned** about them.

**unconcerned** (adj.)

> Not anxious or upset: free of worry [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unconcerned)

> If a person is unconcerned about something, usually something that
> most people would care about, they are **not interested in it or worried
> about it**. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/unconcerned)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps the word you're looking for is **jaded**

> tired, bored, or lacking enthusiasm, typically after having had too much of something

Being surrounded by amazing technology all the time would likely leave one jaded about new technical wonders.

Answer (score 4):

You could say that you've become [**inured**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inure) to these phenomena or events. Though *inured* more often means 'come to tolerate something unpleasant', it can also have the flavor of simply becoming used to something.

Answer (score 1):

To your citizens, the mayor's grand unveiling of the new city-wide FTL bus network is just an **everyday** occurrence.

Groundbreaking technological progression is just their **everyday**.

"Everyday" is an adjective and (less used, although I like this usage) an uncountable noun.

Answer (score 0):

Desensitisation or normalisation.

The citizens have been desensitised to groundbreaking technological achievements.

Releasing a new gene-editing augmentation every day has been normalised.

> **desensitize**
> to cause someone to experience something, usually an emotion or a pain, less strongly than before

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desensitize)

> **normalize**
> To normalize something is to treat it as normal or acceptable when it is not.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/normalize)

Answer (score 0):

#### taken for granted

> 1. to assume (something) as true, real, unquestionable, or **to be expected**
> 2. to value (something or someone) too lightly : **to fail to properly notice or appreciate** (someone or something that should be valued)

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20for%20granted) (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Another word is **accustomed**, [whose definitions include](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accustomed) “adapted to existing conditions,” and “in the habit or custom.”

So, they would be accustomed to their modern conveniences.